# XAMPP how to have multiple applications

Tags: php, apache, xampp

So, I have a project I am working on, but I want to work on a different project which requires a different Apache directory **AND** different MySQL database. I have never really messed with XAMPP configurations so I don't know how to do this, help will be greatly appreciated! *thanks*.

Comment: You can have sub directory and multiple database with xampp, is that want you want? I  am kind of confused

Comment: yes, just how is that done?

Comment: You can achieve multiple applications by having multiple documents roots(each in another dir). You can have as many mysql db's as your configurations allows. You should further expand your question. maybe add your current dir structure etc...

Comment: Why do you need a different Apache directory?

Comment: Define a separate (virtual) host per project/application. Take a look at the documentation of the apache http server on how to do that.

Comment: For the applications, simply create the folders needed into htdocs apache folder. For mysql, create another database normaly and on the new application, add the PHP code for connecting to that database.

Comment: For a better professional development environment, I recommend that you take a look: [Laravel Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead). You will not have problems like this, because directly you write the local domain for working.

Comment: This post is aimed at WAMPServer, but all that is different is the directory structure for XAMPP and Virtual Hosts are a breeze once you get the first one working http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say your DocumentRoot in httpd.conf file is directed to `xampp\htdocs`. Assuming you're trying to set up a WordPress project and a drupal project, create two folders under htdocs `wp` and `drupal` and have your projects inside them. You'll be hitting the projects by `http://localhost/wp` and `http://localhost/drupal`. Create two virtual hosts entries in hosts-config file to give different server URLs to your projects.

Comment: Oh my god, okay I should have noticed that sooner thanks!

Comment: Go for the Virtual Host method as it makes moving sites from test to live more reliable